# Why do I get a TypeError when adding event listners with a for loop?

Tags: javascript

when trying to add a "click" event listener to a single element, it works:

```
var blog1 = document.getElementById("b1");

blog1.addEventListener("click", function(){
window.location.href="blog1.html";
});
```

But, when I try to use a for loop to assign click listeners to multiple elements at once, like so:

```
var blog1 = document.getElementById("b1");
var blog2 = document.getElementById("b2");
var blog3 = document.getElementById("b3");

for(var i =1; i<4; i++){
var k= ("blog" + i );
 k.addEventListener("click", function(){
 window.location.href=(k+".html");
 });
 }
```

I receive the error:

```
TypeError: k.addEventListener is not a function
```

Could anyone tell me where I am going wrong? Many thanks.
P.s- Trying to do this in vanilla JS.

Comment: `k` is just a String. Did you mean to pass it to a `getElementBy` method?

Comment: `("blog" + i )` evaluates to a string. You cannot reference variables this way in JS. If `blogN` variables are defined in the global scope, you can `window['blog' + i].addEventListener`...

Comment: I’d say you are also going wrong here using IDs for this in the first place … go with a class, use getElementsByClassName or querySelectorAll to select those elements, and then just loop over the resulting node list.

Comment: @Carcigenicate- surely I only need a string car, because the result would then be "blog1.html", etc. Which will redirect the page to the various blog posts I have created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var k= ("blog" + i );` will create a string like `blog1`,`blog2`,`blog3`.It will not refer to the element.
You can use `document.getElementById()` directly in loop and use `let` instead of `var`

```
for(let i =1; i<4; i++){
 let blog = document.getElementById("b"+i);
   blog.addEventListener("click", function(){
     window.location.href=(i+".html");
   });
}
```

Comment: @R3tep Thanks I forgot replace it with `i`

Comment: I think it's `("blog" + i )`

Comment: The event listener would be wrong every time, since it would only reference the last value of the loop https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: @VLAZ Nice catch. I fixed it

Comment: Note: solution does work, just needed to change .href(i+".html"); to .href=("blog"+i+".html");

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is to use `eval` that basically evaluates at runtime a String as JavaScript code.
Reference: [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).

```
var blog1 = document.getElementById("b1");
var blog2 = document.getElementById("b2");
var blog3 = document.getElementById("b3");

for(var i =1; i<4; i++){
    var k= eval("blog" + i );
        k.addEventListener("click", function(){
        window.location.href=(k+".html");    
    });
}
```

Be aware that is better not to abuse eval because can bring to a performance and code injection problem. Ref: [When is JavaScript's eval() not evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil).